# Why is float('nan') not equal to itself in python

Tags: python

```
In [6]: a = float('nan')

In [7]: a == a
Out[7]: False
```

Why?

Comment: Because `NaN != NaN`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Not really. He asking about _why_ they behave a certain way, not _how_ they behave a certain way.

Comment: @ChristianDean He'll need to visit https://math.stackexchange.com then

Comment: The correct test probably is `math.isnan(a)`.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ That, I'd tend to agree with you on. What he's asking about really isn't specific to any programming language. That's how most languages implement `NaN`.

Comment: By definition, `NaN` fails *any* comparison.

Answer (score 8):

There are two reasons, one practical and one historical. The historical reason is that this makes it trivial to test for a NaN. If the value isn't equal to itself, it's a NaN.

The practical reason is that NaN is used to indicate various different cases where the value is not defined, and not all undefined values are equal.

Should `NaN`/`NaN` equal 1? Think about how crazy that would be. Arguing that `NaN` should equal itself is only a bit less crazy.

Comment: Interesting. To your question of Should NaN/NaN equal 1?  I think the answer I would give is: simply don't allow division by NaN since it doesn't represent a number, it's like dividing by a string or something

Comment: @nichochar The way you typically disallow something is by having it return a `NaN`. What precisely are you suggesting?

Comment: NaN / NaN -> NaN?

Comment: Yes. This allows a `NaN` to 'bubble up' through a series of computations, so you only have to test the final result for `NaN`.

Comment: I was curious if `math.isnan` would be defined simply as `return a != a` (it is not).